# XML site map is not generating for Magento 2.2.6

Tags: seo, sitemaps, magento2.2.6

I have upgrade the Magento version to 2.2.6. Now i want to configure the sitemap for my site.

I have followed the [document](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/sitemap-xml.html)

but still it showing 404 page not found error..

is it magento 2.2.6 known issue ?

Comment: have u check folder location where sitemap generate

Answer (score 0):

I have done some workaround for this ...

To generate this file directory should be wirtable...

Basically `<magento-root-dir>/pub` is writable..

so I have created /pub/location (here we can not directly put sitemap.xml under pub directory.)

and in the backend i have generated a path ...

```
<magento-root-dir>/pub/location/sitemap.xml
```

my site map is working now

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: First you create any custom folder in your root directory (example : Here is my custom folder name = "sitemap").

(Note: (ex:- sitemap and yes please give full permission to this folder (chmod -R 777 sitemap))

**Step 2**: Magento Admin-->(Marketing->SEO & Search -> Sitemap).

**Step 3**: add a new sitemap. please see below image.

[image]

**Step 4**: Now check your url somthing like ...http://192.168.1.226/magento1/sitemap/sitemap.xml